# Add product in magento Programmatically

Tags: php, magento, product, magento-1.8, programmatically-created

I want to add product in magneto grammatically.My code to save product is below:-

```
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product
        ->setAttributeSetId(4)
        ->setTypeId('simple')
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
        ->setSku($product_sku)
        ->setName($product_name)
        ->setWeight($product_weight)
        ->setStatus($Status)
        ->setTaxClassId(2)
        ->setManufacturer($product_manufacturer) 
        ->setCountryOfManufacture('US')
        ->setPrice($product_price)
        ->setCost($product_price)
        ->setSpecialFromDate(strtotime('now'))
        ->setSpecialToDate() */
        ->setMsrpEnabled(4)
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(4)
        ->setMsrp($wholesale_price)
        ->setDescription($product_short_desc)
        ->setShortDescription($product_short_desc)
        ->setVisibility(4);

        $mediaArray = array(
            'thumbnail' => $imgpath,
            //'small_image' => $imagepath,
            // 'image'       => $imagepath,
        );

        $product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'max_sale_qty' => 200, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => $product_quantity //qty
            )
        )
        ->setCategoryIds($categories); //assign product to categories

       if ($product->save()) 
        {
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->loadByAttribute('sku', $product_sku);
            echo 'Added successfully';
        }
    }
```

After executing the above code,I got the following error:-

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint

violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DBNAME`.`catalog_product_entity`
, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`
) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) O)' in /var/www/xxx/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo
.php:228

Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/xxx/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)

## 1 /var/www/xxx/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array

)

## 2 /var/www/xxx/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute

(Array)

## 3 /var/www/xxx/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

## 4 /var/www/xxx/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT

INTO `ca...', Array)

5 /var/www/xxx/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->qu in

> /var/www/xxx/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line **234**

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:-
I set the category id by using

```
    ->setCategoryIds($categories); //assign product to categories
```

And now I used

```
    ->setCategoryIds(array($categories)); //assign product to categories
```

where $categories = '2,3,5';